# Converting float/double/decimal to (u)int, (u)long in C# without memory allocation

Tags: c#, networking, type-conversion

I am working on the c# networking solution for my game, and I have a problem with serializing `float`s, `double`s, and `decimal`s.

My first attempt - `BitConverter` class. But each time I use that class, a new byte[] array is created, and this may be overkill for my net solution (for example - player position synchronization).

To summarize, my expectation is:

- Possibility to convert `float`s, `double`s, and `decimal`s into (u)int, (u)long without memory allocation.
- Possibility to read (u)int's and (u)longs from server & convert the, back to the original type (still without allocating additional memory).

**Edit 1**

This is method I use in my NetworkWriter method to store bytes to send:

```cs
public void WriteByte(byte value)
        {
            Buffer[_position++] = value;
        }
```

And those are my extensions for NetworkWriter:

```
public static void WriteUInt(this NetworkWriter writer, uint value)
        {
            writer.WriteByte((byte) value);
            writer.WriteByte((byte) (value >> 8));
            writer.WriteByte((byte) (value >> 16));
            writer.WriteByte((byte) (value >> 24));
        }
```

That's I want to cast 4-byte float to 4-byte (u)int, so I can pass the result int to the Write(U)Int serializer.

I haven't done the NetworkReader yet, so I cannot show you the exact code, but it's gonna revert the Write method.

I expect a lot of float/double operations, because:

- Vector3 (class that holds player position) is a pack of 3 floats,
- Latency measuring will send/receive double time
- Quaternion (class that holds player rotation) is also pack of 4 floats.

That's why I wanna reduce memory allocation for float/double/decimal as much as possible.

**Edit 2**

Important note: I know when to expect float, double, etc, let me quickly pseudocode how will reader look like:

```
static float ReadFloat():
- Get 4 int bytes from buffer
- Construct float from those
```

Comment: You just need to cast.  Bitconvert is only used when you have to byte array.  You have a number and just converting to a different number.  Converting a floating point number to int or long is going to remove the accuracy of the results.  You could also use Math.Abs(float).

Comment: BitConverter has a `Int64BitsToDouble` and its counter part that doesn't create a byte array. Show us what your input is and what the output should be. Also: are you sure that your network latency is so low already that you're really going to notice the time/memory these small allocations needs? How many do you expect?

Comment: Just casting is losing precision. I tried it. And @rene - I am editing question rn

Comment: Then explain how you expect to go from a decimal to a long, or multiple longs as you would need two of those to not lose precision.

Comment: Yeah, the decimal will probably go to two long values. And basically it is my question - how to convert float/double/dec values into easy-serializable int's, longs and 2 longs.

Comment: @rene Important edit, check it.

Comment: Is NetworkWriter that class from Unity3d?

Comment: No. I am doing own networking solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of options:

- `BitConverter` has methods like `Int32BitsToSingle(Int32)` (from and to, 32-bit and 64-bit)  that does a bitwise coerce between primitives; from there you can get unsigned trivially
- `BinaryPrimitives` has read and write methods for many primitives that work on spans; spans can be on the stack for zero-allocation (or better: can be in your output buffer)
- your own `unsafe` code; take the address of a local/parameter/field/interior-pointer, and coerce the pointer before dereferencing it
- the `Unsafe` type (and the `As` method in particular) allows direct coercion between same-size primitives from a `ref` (like the `unsafe` option, but pre-written, and uses IL to avoid the unmanaged pointer)
- the `MemoryMarshal` type (and the `Cast` method in particular) allows the same direct conversion on *spans* of types, including between different sized types; in particular, this allows you to cast any primitive that doesn't contain a reference: to a `Span<byte>`